# Using JHipster's generated tests in a similar project

Tags: testing, automation, jhipster

I have an existing Java Spring Boot project which has zero test cases - all testing is manual. Let's call this app as MyApp.

I am thinking of

1. Using JHipster to create an app similar to MyApp - let's call it HipApp.
2. Copying tests from HipApp to MyApp
3. Automating various tests in MyApp

Is this a feasible and reasonable approach?

Basically, the ask is to automate the generation of test cases for an existing Java Spring Boot project, and then use manual effort to handle scenarios that cannot be generated automatically.

I am looking at UnLogged, TackleTest-Unit, CodiumAI, and JHipster. I like JHipster as it's free, mature, and generates various categories of tests (Unit, Integration, Load, etc.).

Am I on the right track?

I tried to see if there was a way to import an existing codebase into JHipster. Does NOT look like that that is feasible.

Comment: I don't think this will work. I'd recommend looking at a generated app for testing patterns and use those as ideas for testing your no-tests-project.

Comment: @MattRaible, fair enough - but can you comment about *why* you think this will not work?

Comment: Because the tests are typically closely tied to the code they're testing. They contain certain endpoints, expect certain data, etc. If you're copying all the tests into your project, you'll likely be modifying so much test code to work with your code that it'd be easier if you wrote your tests from scratch.

Comment: It'd be very similar business functionality however. Anyway, if I do go this route, I will update with the results.